# null safety without elvis operator kotlin

Tags: kotlin

`a ?: b`  is just shorthand for `if (a != null) a else b`.

I understand that `?:` eliminates the danger of null references from code. However I encountered fragment, which I failed to re-write myself. Here it is:
`

```
val words = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
input = scan.next()
wordCounts[input] = (wordCounts[input] ?: 0) + 1
```

What I tried is:

```
words[input] = if (words[input] != null) (words[input]+1) else 0
```

However Intelij displays error here
[image]

After I replaced it with its sugesttion I have further errors:

```
 words[input] = if (words[input] != null) (words[input]?.plus(1)) else 0
```

[image]

How can I fix that if statement remain?

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the usages of the elvis operators in the first place?

For the record what's happening here is that `words[input]` might change value between you checking for it in the `if` and evaluating it in in the `then`. Furthermore `1` should be added to the result of the `if` not just in the `then` branch

Comment: I don''t understand your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```kotlin
val n = words[input]
words[input] = if (n != null) n + 1 else 0
```

`words` might change value to become `null` after your `if` statement, so you should capture the variable first and then do the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

> `a ?: b` is just shorthand for `if (a != null) a else b`

That's *almost* true.  But there's one subtle difference: the elvis version only evaluates `a` once, while the other evaluates it twice — carrying the possibility that it could give a different result each time.

In this case, `a` is `words[input]`.  What if another thread changes the contents of `words` in between the two evaluations, removing the value for key `input` so that `words[input]` returns null the second time?  (Even if you know that no other thread could possibly be accessing it, if the compiler can't prove that, it has to assume that the second time could give a null result.)

So the solution is to evaluate it only once.

You can do that with a temporary variable, as per another answer.  But Kotlin's scoping functions give you a slightly simpler option:

```
words[input].let{ if (it != null) it + 1 else 1 }
```

This works because [`let()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) is an extension method defined on `Any?`, so (unlike ‘real’ methods) it's safe to call on a null.

However, this just illustrates why the elvis operator is useful, and how it simplifies some code!  You don't explain why you want to rewrite your code to avoid it; that could be a useful learning exercise, but in practice you'd just use the elvis operator instead.